# Where To Install Tar.GZ File?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lubuntu

I have download a .tar.gz file and I am running Lubuntu.  Once "installed" I would lie the file to show up in the categories under "start."  Where should I extract the files to in order for this to occur?  The command I will be using to extract is:

```
sudo tar -xvf nameoffile.tar.gz
```

And if it matters to the install location, the file I want to install is tiny media manager (for renaming moves/tv shows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inclusion of an item in the LXPanel menu is unrelated to where the application is installed.

For the most part, you want to install user software in the home, if it is isolated to one user, or in `/opt` if it is to be shared amongst users. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

As for the LXPanel menu, in LXDE you do this by creating a `.desktop` file for the app, and placing it in `/usr/share/applications`, `/usr/local/share/applications`, or `~/.local/share/applications`.

To create a `.desktop` file, LXDE ships a utility called [LXShortcut](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXShortCut). It will help you create a name for the launcher, point it to a command, and even set an icon.

See more here: https://lkubaski.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/adding-lxde-start-menu-and-desktop-shortcuts/